# How to create initializer for subclass of SKScene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, skscene

I am Swift and Xcode, trying to make a simple text adventure for iOS. The game starts at the GameScene that has a Start button. When it registers a tap on the button, it moves to the first PlayScene instance. It has some text (a description of the scene) and two options (buttons A and B). When it registers a tap on a button, it moves to the corresponding PlayScene instance. And so on until it reaches an EndScene that has only text and a button to restart.

My idea was to implement an initializer for PlayScene that would take the text that a scene is supposed to have and the next scenes that should follow. So in my PlayScene.swift I added the following:

```
let sceneText: String
let nextSceneA: PlayScene
let nextSceneB: PlayScene

init(sceneText: String, nextSceneA: PlayScene, nextSceneB: PlayScene) {
    self.sceneText = sceneText
    self.nextSceneA = nextSceneA
    self.nextSceneB = nextSceneB
}
```

I get this error:

> 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'SKScene'

Does that mean there is no way to create a custom initializer for a subclass of SKScene? How else can I implement a sequence of scenes like that?

Comment: Just implement `init(coder:)` and have it throw an error.  Xcode should offer to do this for you if click the red stop sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement init(coder:), even if all it does is return an error.

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Comment: Hi! I tried doing what Xcode offered. I got another error: `Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer`

Comment: I added `super.init()` after at the end of my custom initializer and it worked.